# Cocoa PreferencePane User Defaults always stored in com.apple.systempreferences.plist

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, preferences

I'm developing a PreferencePane in Xcode 4.1, and I can't seem to get it to store the preference values in anything other than com.apple.systempreferences.plist.

I have set the Bundle Identifier for my app in the MyApp-Info.plist file, but this does not seem to be getting picked up.

I have searched extensively for an answer, but cannot find any. You can easily replicate the problem as follows:

**In XCode:**

1. Create a new PreferencePane project
2. Add a NSTextField to the .xib
3. Bind the text field value to Shared User Defaults Controller, with any key name
4. Build the project
5. Right-click on the icon under Products and select "Open with External Editor" to install to System Preferences (this user only)

**In System Preferences:**

1. Open your pref pane, and type any value in the text box.
2. See that your preference value is saved in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist

But why doesn't it create a new plist file with your specified bundle identifier, and store the preference value in there?

Is this a bug in Xcode 4.1 / Mac OS 10.7 ? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to access the defaults for your bundle ID:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:@"yourBundleID"];
```

This will return a dictionary with the preferences for your bundle. You can then use the `setPersistentDomain:forName:` method of `NSUserDefaults` to store an updated preferences dictionary.

Comment: Awesome - this is exactly what I did, and it worked! Thx v much

Answer (score 0):

Not a bug -- preferences are stored into the plist corresponding to the application, not the bundle. You'll have to use the [Core Foundation prefs system](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-108766) to read and write preferences specific to your bundle.